pywin32 (4096, Microsoft Outlook, access route doesn't exist)
I created an application from Python using Nuitka, and when running a distribution in a different PC the function of sending emails with an attachment is not working using pywin32. The following exemption is shown:

Failed to send email: (-2147352567, Exemption occured, (4096, Microsoft Outlook' The access route doesn't exist. Corroborate the the access route is correct, None, 0, -2147024893), None)

The executable is working appropriately in the development PC including the mail function.
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
def Send_mail():
    try:
        pythoncom.CoInitialize() # Ensure COM initialization
#        destination = email_entry.get()
        ol = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
        # size of the new email
        olmailitem = 0x0
        newmail = ol.CreateItem(olmailitem)
        newmail.Subject = 'Test'
        newmail.To = ';'.join(recipient_emails)
        #newmail.CC = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    
        newmail.Body= 'Hello'
    
        attach = 'file.xlsx' # File created with script, stored in executable folder
        newmail.Attachments.Add(attach)
    
        newmail.Display()
        # Clear recipient email list
        recipient_emails.clear()
        
    except Exception as e:
        # Show error message if any exception occurs
        messagebox.showerror("Error", f"Failed to send email: {str(e)}")
        
def add_email():
    email = email_entry.get().strip()
    if email:
        recipient_emails.append(email)
        email_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    
    tree_mail.insert('', tk.END, values=email)


Which line of your code throws that error?

I would think that is this line: win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application') Since the error only happens with the executable in other PCs I don't have too much information. The issue is in the communication with Outlook.

When and how does your code run?
